# In g++, when do you get <error-type> in the error message for a failed template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

I've recently gone back to writing C++ and am still a bit rusty after severa years away from it.

I'm trying to compile some templated code, and am getting the following error message

```
error: no instance of function template "my_nice_function" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (int*, <error-type>, size_t)
```

for a function taking a `T*`, a `const T*` and a `size_t`.

What does the `<error-type>` mean? What, in general, are the causes for getting an `<error-type>` in a G++ error message?

Comment: I *think* it means it's an erroneous type, one that the compiler could not determine, for other reasons. How did you ascertain it is a `const T*`? (Also, are there no other errors?)

Comment: If you think seeing your template function decl and the point in the source where this message is generated would be helpful, you'd be right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I was asking the more general question of when you get this kind of errors. Actually, SebastianrRedl has given me the answer I was looking for; however, it's obscured by the wording and my edit is not accepted.

Comment: @einpoklum: Stack Overflow expects concrete questions about an actual problem that you've faced. Part of that is providing a testcase showing what you're doing. Otherwise, sometimes, we can only _guess_ and this is one of those times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function may *take* a `const T*`, but the compiler is complaining that you are *passing* an `<error-type>`, i.e. an expression that the compiler could not determine the type of.

If you want a more detailed answer, you will need to show your code, especially the calling code.

Comment: Actually, the rest of the code involves CUDA, and I didn't want to make this about CUDA, but your answer was helpful. Editing it a bit to emphasize the helpful part.

Comment: @einpoklum: Make a pure C++ testcase.